# Pronto hex code to base64, How to convert

Tags: base64, hex, infrared, pronto

I have a device that accepts pronto code as input, I have a comment list in base64, can you help me convert it, I was unable to find the answer how to do it.
My base64 code list: https://github.com/smartHomeHub/SmartIR/blob/master/codes/climate/2160.json